# Fragment Animation and stop at a particular level android

Tags: android, fragment, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

I am using fragments in my application. I am at **fragment A** and I click on a button in `Fragment A`. That time I want my **Fragment B** to appear with an animation . `Fragment B` has to appear from the Bottom and stop at the center of the screen.

So now I can see my Fragment A at the top and Fragment B at the bottom. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Place both fragments in a vertical LinearLayout and then animate the bottom fragment's height.

Comment: @velis: can u post some code?

Comment: That would be a lot of code as you need Animation, interpolator, etc. You should read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html - I made it work rather easily after reading that